# PHPExcel - convert csv with leading zeros to xls

Tags: excel, csv

I have generated by online store csv file, in this file there are some products that have article starting from 000. If open csv file, leading zeros will disappear. I would like to convert it into xls file to keep leading zeros. I tried:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_CSV();
$objReader->setInputEncoding('UTF8');
$objReader->setDelimiter(';');
$objReader->setEnclosure('');
$objReader->setLineEnding("\r\n");
$objReader->setSheetIndex(0);

$objReader->loadIntoExisting("files/test.csv", $objPHPExcel);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel2007");
$objWriter->save("files/test.xlsx");
```

But leading zeros are still disappear. I tried to add row to make column format as string:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:A10000')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode( PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );
```

But result is the same.

Comment: Open Excel first, then see if you can import data from a CSV file. Doesn't it give an import wizard where you can define the data types of columns? If so, import as a string.

Comment: When you generate your data, place a single quote (apostrophe) in front of values that may start with leading zeros.

Comment: We need to place generated xls file on our server, then dealers will download and import it to their program automatically, so it is impossible for them to open it and import through wizard each time.

Comment: Where did you put that `setFormatCode()` in your code? Before or after importing the CSV file?

Comment: Before importing csv file. The cells have text format after that, but leading zeros disappear anyway

Comment: I see...what about the amount of zeros or characters, is it constant? You could always re-add them if that's the case.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, because some have 000, some have 00, some doesn't have any... But I solved the problem, updated script to export from database directly to Excel, skipping csv. Thanks!